# Glassfish file realm portability

Tags: glassfish

Is it possible to somehow copy glassfish File Realm configuration (that is - users with stored passwords) between glassfish installations?

I thought all the required user info was contained within *keyfile* file, however that's not the case. As far as I can tell passwords are hashed with some salt added (different hash is generated each time for the same password) and as a result after copying to another installation they no longer work.

Would it be possible to maybe copy the salt info, wherever it is stored? Or find out what the salt is and generate SHA hash manually? Or is the problem somewhere else entirely?

I know I could use asadmin to simply generate it again at each installation, but that is another step in the process, and I am already copying other parts of configuration (like *domain.xml*).

Answer (score 0):

I have migrated the `keyfile` between Glassfish versions such as Glassfish4.1 to Glassfish4.1.1 and even to Payara41 without any problems, often.

Depending on your `<security-role>` and `<security-constraint>` settings, you may also have to ensure that this is set in the admin console:

```
[x] Default Principal To Role Mapping Enabled
```

This is under:

```
Configurations > server-config > Security.
```

Be sure to use `server-config` not `default-config`.

If you are using the same web app on the newer/other Glassfish server you probably have something like the following anyway; In any case if you are doing FORM authentication against the file realm you'll need this in web.xml:

```
<!-- JAAS FORM authentication: j_security_check -->
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```